# Pictures appeared in the new Photos app in my new laptop. Where are these files?

Tags: photos

My brand new laptop populated the Photos app with my photos. Problem is I don't know where these files are. Unlike with iTunes, right-clicking and selecting Get Info doesn't show where the original file is.

If I go to the Pictures folder I see an icon for Photo Library. If I click it, it fires up Photos. Again, I see no files.

Comment: where did you get the from (populated)

Comment: Photos stores your library in the Pictures folder on your Mac by default. If you upgrade an iPhoto or Aperture library, your Photos library will be stored in the same location as the original library.